# Why does PostMessage not work with all VK values?

Tags: c#, keydown, postmessage, keyup

I'm attempting to simulate keyboard input to an window programmatically. I realize [SendInput](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-sendinput) is the optimal method here, but I need to be able to send this keystroke to a window that is not currently in focus.

As such, I'm trying to use [PostMessage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-postmessage) instead.

The following works for simulating the input of the F5 key in notepad, but not for the spacebar.

```
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
static extern bool PostMessage(IntPtr hWnd, UInt32 msg, uint wParam, int lParam);

const uint WM_KEYDOWN = 0x0100;
const uint WM_KEYUP = 0x0101;
const int VK_SPACE = 0x20;
const int VK_F5 = 0x74;

while(true)
{
    Process[] processes = Process.GetProcessesByName("notepad");
    foreach (Process process in processes)
    {
        PostMessage(process.MainWindowHandle, WM_KEYDOWN, VK_F5, 0);
        PostMessage(process.MainWindowHandle, WM_KEYUP, VK_F5, 0);
        Thread.Sleep(5000);
        PostMessage(process.MainWindowHandle, WM_KEYDOWN, VK_SPACE, 0);
        PostMessage(process.MainWindowHandle, WM_KEYUP, VK_SPACE, 0);
    }
}
```

Any idea why? Is there a better why I should go about this?

Comment: This answer suggests that you may need to dig in deeper: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/324f1962-b072-4fd4-9034-036237d179e6/send-keystrokes-to-an-unfocused-window?forum=vbgeneral#878abbf9-dc45-4a4a-88cf-6b31846daad6-isAnswer 
 Very often, application windows are composite, and consist of ***multiple actual windows*** with different handles. The HWND you got is only the top-level outer window, toolbar, menu and menu items will have their own, status bar as well, and the answer linked points out that the TEXT AREA is also a window and has its own handle.

Comment: Each window from the composite will handle some keys differently. If you send an enter/space/etc to a menuitem, it will react as a click/select. If you send it to textarea, it will be treated as text input to be appened/inserted. F5 sent to the outer frame probably was handled as an accelerator key (hot key), which, for notepad, could be globally understood as 'paste date' action, but "space" probably flies another route, as it is heavily contextual. I dont really know. But I know that composite windows are all about chaining and filtering and passing messages around,so that must have happened

Comment: Try some window-scanning utility like Spy++ or ProcessHacker2 and its 'windows' module, and see what your Windows's Notepad's window exactly consists of. If you see that 'textarea' is a window itself, try sending keys directly to its HWND instead of the outer frame. That should do the trick. But, if it's some version of a notepad that doesn't have a composite window and i.e. is a single-area rendered with WPF or whatever, then I have no idea - should work as you had it since it's only 1 window. So.. not an answer, just some hints from me :)